# XML HTTP request with phonegap doesnt connect always

Tags: javascript, php, android, cordova

I have a phonegap app that uses XMLHTTP Request to communicate with a PHP file, the problem is that it connects alright but after a while it doesn't seem to connect again. and then It comes up again, i.e it goes off and on. the Js COde is as follows

```
function news(){
//if(isPhoneGapReady && isConnected){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            localStorage.news=xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById('item').innerHTML=localStorage.news;

        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://url.com",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
//}
```

}